# Join two tables on Telephone Numbers where the numbers are in differing formats

Tags: sql-server

I have an interesting / frustrating problem for which I already have a solution - however it's slow and I'm not convinced is the best way of solving it.

I have two tables I wish to join. The first I'll refer to as [MobileNumber] and the Second [MobileInventory]. The table [MobileNumber] contains numbers in the format 7123456789. The table [MobileInventory] contains numbers that may be in any one of the following three formats - 7123456789, 07123456789, +447123456789. I need to join the two and the only common field is the mobile number.

The two issues are, within [MobileInventory] I can't guarantee the format (export of external system) and the numbers in both tables are from multiple countries with different length country codes (+1, +44, +852) and within [MobileNumber] I have no way of telling which country a number is from. This makes it very hard just to remove the first x characters from [MobileInventory] or do a replace on any known country code (risky!) and have done with.

My solution (**working**):

```
SELECT *
FROM [MobileNumber]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [MobileInventory]
ON CHARINDEX(REVERSE([MobileNumber].[Number]), REVERSE([MobileInventory]),1) = 1
```

With both numbers reversed its easy to see if you get the position of [MobileNumber].[Number] in [MobileInventory].[Mobile] and if the result is 1 - it's a match.

9876543217

98765432170

987654321744+

98765432174400

This works, and I get a very good match result - however, its SO SLOW! I have c.50k numbers in [MobileNumber] and c.20k in [MobileInventory].

Next thing to try is (as I'm using the result in the above in a MERGE in a Stored Procedure) to take a GUID from [MobileInvetory] and store in [MobileNumber] for later view joins, so I *could* achieve this using a cursor in a cursor to make the comparison but I'm not convinced that will be any quicker.

I have checked similar questions and the problems solved seem to be with separators, or consistent country codes which don't apply to my issue.

The above is automated via a scheduled task, so I could just kick it off earlier in the day, but that doesn't seem right somehow!

Comment: A cursor is going to be slower, not faster. The problem is that you are forced to use functions when joining. This means that any indexing is hopeless because this is nonSARGable. Both REVERSE and CHARINDEX are killing your performance. But given the nature of how the data is inconsistent I don't know a good way around it. Your data almost forces you to do a row by row search here which is going to be terrible no matter how you slice it.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange. Appreciate your time. Do you think if I performed the REVERSE in a CTE or TempTable this would speed it up?

Comment: Can you normalize the numbers, especially do you have a default country prefix for numbers without? Or do you have a table of country prefixes (or can you generate one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this. Using just code here are 2 alternatives.

```
SELECT *
FROM [MobileNumber]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [MobileInventory]
ON [MobileNumber].[Number] = RIGHT([MobileInventory], LEN([MobileNumber].[Number]));

SELECT *
FROM [MobileNumber]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [MobileInventory]
ON [MobileInventory] LIKE '%' + [MobileNumber].[Number];
```

The first one <strike>expects all numbers to be 10 digits long, but I´m not sure if some countries could have shorter numbers.</strike> takes the length of the Mobile Number.

You could also create a persisted computed column on MobileInventory to index the column and create a more efficient join.

Comment: Thanks @LuisCazares. Top option won't work as I'm dealing with multiple countries and mobile numbers do differ in length. Second one also works, but is actually slower than the REVERSE/CHARINDEX solution above.

Comment: I modified the first option, but I'm not sure that it would be any improvement in performance. You really need to do some data cleansing to optimize this query.

Comment: I think option one might just work, and should be a lot quicker. I’ll knock up a test script this evening and will publish my findings! Will be sure to mark your answer as the resolution if it solves. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks @LuisCazares. I actually have three instances of [MobileInventory]. I have only updated the join part of the merge for each statement. First is 3k rows which did take 15mins and now takes 5mins. Second is 4k rows which did take 45mins and now takes 20mins. Last which I never ran all way through takes 3hours. I can still make some efficiency savings but I've marked this as the answer as I wanted something faster and the first option above fits the bill nicely! Thanks very much for your help!